# Unexpected token (>) while rendering array using map function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create render a table using map function in React. This particular piece of code is causing an error "Unexpected token :operator (>)". Is there something wrong with my code? I am a newbie at JS as well as React.

```
const renderReportsForManager = React.useCallback(
            function (managerId) {
                const reportsData = getReportsData();
                return {
                    childRows: reportsData.map((row) => (
                        <MyTable.Row data-id={row.id} key={row.id} level={2}>
                            <MyTable.Cell data-id="name">{row.name}</MyTable.Cell>
                            <MyTable.Cell data-id="email">{row.email}</MyTable.Cell>
                        </MyTable.Row>
                    )),
                };
            },
            [getReportsData]
        );
```

Comment: `Unexpected token (>)` sounds like some json is being parsed, where `>` is encountered on end of that. Likely html is being parsed as json **but if you give the actual "error/stack trace"** *verbatim*, then more helpful help could be provided, as more insights would exist.

Comment: I guess your project is not using babel-jsx properly, did you use `create-react-app` to setup your project?